# In Magento2, Region/State is not showing on address in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, address

I'm barely new to Magento2 and Magento in general.
The version I'm using is ----> 2.4.3-p1

I'm facing this issue: when I add a new Address in checkout page, it doesn't show the Region/State field, but just the city.

I don't know why this is happening, also if I try to checkout with that second address, I got this error `Please specify a regionId in shipping address.`

So I'm trying to solve these issues.

In this screenshot I'm showing you the problem with that missing Region/State text.

For formatting the addresses I've created these two files, overwriting them:

1. `app/design/frontend/Magenio/vyvo/CommunityEngineering_JapaneseAddress/web/template/checkout/shipping-information/address-renderer/jp.html`
2. `app/design/frontend/Magenio/vyvo/CommunityEngineering_JapaneseAddress/web/template/checkout/shipping-address/address-renderer/jp.html`

And everything works fine, except for that missing text and the error when doing the checkout choosing the second address.

[image]

If you can help me understand guys it would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change settings at Store > Configuration > General > General > State Options

[image]

Comment: I've tried this solution before, but nothing changed unfortunately. Now in "State is Required for" I choosed Italy, and in "Allow to Choose State if it is Optional for Country" I choosed Yes. I did it again, and did bin/magento c:f, but still that Region/State is missing.

Comment: did you try doing it on the specific store view?

Comment: No I didn't, at least I think I didn't, how could I do that?

Comment: In the upper left corner, under the title "Configuration", there is a dropdown menu "Scope". Try also to modify "Country options"

Comment: Ok I'll try and let you know as fast as possible, thanks :)

Comment: I tried to set "italiano" under Scope, then check again in General -> State Options but this one was missing. There's only Country Options, Locale Options and Store Address Template. And in the page the Region/State is still missing

Comment: Yes sorry, my mistake, that option is a global scope option

Comment: No problem, thanks for helping anyways :)

Comment: @D.D. Please let us know the solution which you used to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue you're facing, kindly follow the steps below:

1. Firstly, make a copy of the 'vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js' file.
2. Then, navigate to your custom theme directory, located at 'app/design/frontend/[NameSpace]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js'.
3. Paste the copied 'shipping.js' file into this directory, overwriting the existing file.
4. Once you've done this, locate the 'saveNewAddress' function within the 'shipping.js' file.
5. Replace the existing code within this function with the updated code.

   ```
         /**
         * Save new shipping address
         */
        saveNewAddress: function () {
            var addressData,
                newShippingAddress;

            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.triggerShippingDataValidateEvent();

            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                addressData = this.source.get('shippingAddress');
                // if user clicked the checkbox, its value is true or false. Need to convert.
                addressData['save_in_address_book'] = this.saveInAddressBook ? 1 : 0;
                if(addressData['region_id'] && $('[name="region_id"]').attr("aria-required")){
                    addressData['region'] = $('[name="region_id"]').find("option:selected").attr("data-title");
                }else{
                    addressData['region'] = $('[name="region"]').val();
                }
                // New address must be selected as a shipping address
                newShippingAddress = createShippingAddress(addressData);
                selectShippingAddress(newShippingAddress);
                checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(newShippingAddress.getKey());
                checkoutData.setNewCustomerShippingAddress($.extend(true, {}, addressData));
                this.getPopUp().closeModal();
                this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
            }
        },
   ```

These steps should help you resolve the issue you're encountering.